# How to change the color of my dropdown in my navbar after clicking outside? -Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a template using Bootstrap 3 and I am having this problem.

In my navbar-default, I have a dropdown menu. By default, the dropdown-toggle's font has a grayish color with a transparent background. On hover, the gray turns white. On clicking, the dropdown-menu opens and the toggle itself turns white and its background color becomes a darker shade of blue(focus and active).

However, if I click anywhere outside with the dropdown-menu open, for a second, the color of the toggle's font turns dark-gray, and the background turns cloud-color. After a second or so, it goes back to normal. Its very jarring to me and I can't seem to find the CSS responsible for this. (I am using bootstrap 3)

Anyway, take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32kC7.png) to get a better understanding of what I mean.

This is on my navbar btw.

And finally, here's my code:

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="brand-name"> My brand</span></a>
            </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Username</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My reviews</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
```

And I am changing the colors for hover, active and focus using this CSS code:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-toggle:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-toggle:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: ((Dark blue color code));
 }
```

Any way to change this so that it just goes back to normal instead of the 1-second-color-change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
     .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-toggle{
           choose what color u want to
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-toggle:focus,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-toggle:hover
     {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: ((Dark blue color code));
     }
```